# While Loop Crashing because Key-Value pair doesn't exist after HTTP Request

Tags: python, json, key-value

I have a function that fetches information from a [GitHub API](https://api.github.com/repos/git/git).

The problem is, if the API, which includes the `User` and `Repo` doesn't exist it returns `{message , "Not Found"}`

So I'm running a `while loop` that keeps looking until the username and repo is entered correctly, so the API returns the correct information.

The problem is, when its correct, the `while` loop breaks because the `message` key doesn't exist anymore

```
githubuser = input("GitHub Username: ")
githubrepo = input("GitHub Repo: ")
r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/" + githubuser + "/" + githubrepo)
data = json.loads(r.content)
class User:
    def __init__(self, json_def):
        self.__dict__ = data
user = User(data)

while user.message:
    print("User or Repository not found, please re-enter...")
    githubuser = input("GitHub Username: ")
    githubrepo = input("GitHub Repo: ")
    r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/" + githubuser + "/" + githubrepo)
    data = json.loads(r.content)
   user = User(data)
```

Is there a way I can have a while statement, that when `user.message` doesn't exist anymore it doesn't crash with the error: `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'message'`

I've tried to implement `while user.message != None` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about structuring your code this way?

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.__dict__ = data

user = User({})
while(true):
    githubuser = input("GitHub Username: ")
    githubrepo = input("GitHub Repo: ")
    r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/" + githubuser + "/" + githubrepo)
    data = json.loads(r.content)
    if "message" in data.keys():
       continue
    else:
      user = User(data)
      break
```

Comment: I had to re-arrange as data isn't defined when the class is above you defining data. So as soon as I put the class below the data = json.loads, it worked

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
if hasattr(user, 'message'):
    # user.message here
```

and in your problem use it like so :

```
...
r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/" + githubuser + "/" + githubrepo)
data = json.loads(r.content)
user = User(data)
if not hasattr(user, 'message'):
    break
```